# Bootstrap menu button on smaller screen

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i am trying to build my navigation bar using bootstrap, but i have the issues that when i have a small screen or window the mobile menu button doesn't appear in the right corner. What did i do wrong?

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
            </button>

        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#blog">Blog</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

and my css:

```
.navbar{
    background-color:#fff;
    border-bottom:1px solid black;
}


.navbar-nav > li > a{
    color:#1E88E5 !important;
    font-size:16px !important;
    font-weight:bold !important;
    display: block !important;
    background-color:#fff !important;
}

.navbar-nav > li > a:hover{
    color:#673ab7 !important;
    background-color:#f0f5f5 !important;
}
```

Comment: Have you checked include js such as jquery.js,bootstrap.min.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot navbar style class in your `nav` element (`navbar-default` or `navbar-inverse`). Styling toggle button depends on this class.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
```

Comment: Yes, using the navbar-default and changing the look of this class solved it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

including bootstrap.min.css & bootstrap.css in links would do it.

Comment: i included everything